g4f's provider gpt-3.5-turbo returns chinese response
I am using Python 3.8 to prompt g4f to reply to a specific question, I use it as follows:
from g4f.client import Client

client = Client()
response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "someQuestion"}],
    )
print(response.choices[0].message.content)

But I have noticed that sometimes the response is written in chinese. How to make it return only english responses all the time? is it by changing the provider?
